# Unable to fetch for each value of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to fetch an array of the array from API into the form and also won't able to update that data.

I try this method.
fetch a value from API and inserted as patch value in form and want iterate to form an array.

```
 this.quizForm.patchValue({
        name: name,
        order: this.position,
        type: type,
        path: null,
        quizTime: quizTime,
        quizInstruction: quizInstruction,
        questionList:questionList.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element);  
        })
      })
```

getting an error with data:-

[image]

When I get data From API it shows only 1st object of the array in the form.  console.log(questionList);
console.log(this.quizForm.value.questionList);

response:-

[image]

Quiz form:-

```
 createQuizForm() {
    this.quizForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      type: ['quiz'],
      path: [null],
      order: this.position,
      quizTime: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*$')]],
      quizInstruction: ['', Validators.required],
      questionList: this.fb.array([this.initQuestions()]),

    })
  }

  initQuestions(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      questionText: ['', Validators.required],
      optionList: this.fb.array([this.initOptions()])
    })
  }

  initOptions(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      optionText: ['', Validators.required],
      isAnswer: ['true', Validators.required]
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why do you try to iterate over the "patched" questionList?

Comment: As @Batajus  said, you don't need to iterate. Just assign fetched list to your array

Comment: can you add your response over here

Comment: When i get data From API it shows only 1st object of the array in the form.

Comment: Please refer the update

Comment: We need more context to understand what's going on. Where is `questionList` set? How is `quizForm` defined?

Comment: And btw, applying forEach on questionList will return undefined, so you shouldn't do that

Comment: your expected value in questionList?

Comment: @ShamPooSham Please refer update.

Comment: @ArunkumarRamasamy expected value in questionList but not going into the form questionList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the help of below code my problem is solved --

```
 const question = this.quizForm.get('questionList') as FormArray;

      question.clear();
      questionList.forEach(element => {
        question.push(
          this.fb.group({
            id:element.id,
            questionText:element.questionText,
            optionList:this.setOptions(element)
          })
        )
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` will throw error if the property on which it is applied is undefined.

just do following changes,

```
this.quizForm.patchValue({
        name: name,
        order: this.position,
        type: type,
        path: null,
        quizTime: quizTime,
        quizInstruction: quizInstruction,
        questionList: questionList?.forEach(element => {  // ? is added (assuming that you are working on typescript
          console.log(element);  
        })
      })
```

Comment: In typescript '?' is allowed for null check?

Comment: Yes. It is allowed. if it is not supported in your code then check the typescript version.